# Show that $\ln(K/y) \ge 1 - y/K$ when $0 < y \le K$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

My goal is to prove that the Logistic model of growth $$\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t} = r\left(1-\frac{y}{K} \right)y$$ is always less than the Gompertz model of growth$$\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t} = ry\ln \left(\frac{K}{y} \right),$$ when $0 < y \le K$ (here $r$ and $K$ are positive constants).

So I need to prove that $$ry\ln \left(\frac{K}{y} \right) \ge ry(1-\frac{y}{k}) \Leftrightarrow \ln \left(\frac{K}{y} \right) \ge \left(1-\frac{y}{k} \right)$$

I started by defining $$\phi(y) = \ln \left(\frac{K}{y} \right) - \left(1-\frac{y}{k} \right)  = \ln \left(\frac{K}{y} \right) + \frac{y}{k} - 1,$$ and noted that $\phi(0) = 0$. I then proceeded to try and show that $\phi'(y) \ge 0$ on this interval, which would then imply that $\phi(y) \ge 0$, proving the statement. However, I have had no success with this approach. I'm not sure how else I would be able to prove this statement ... some hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f(x)=\ln(x)+(1-x),\ x\in(0,1]\implies f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}-1\ge 0\implies f$ is monotonic increasing in $(0,1]\implies f(x)\le f(1)=0$ and your result follows by putting $x=\frac{y}{K}$

Comment: The problem is that I have $\ln(K/y)$ in the LHS and not $\ln(y/K)$.

Comment: Reversing the fraction wouldn't work because $x$ would depend on $K/y$ and we would need to use chain rule when differentiating

Comment: You need to show $f(y/K)\le 0$ right? Then I do not see a problem. Recall, $\ln (1/x)=-\ln x$. So,even if you retain $y$, the function will be $g(y)=\ln (y/K)+(1-y/K)\implies g'(y)=\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{K}\ge 0\implies g$ is monotonic increasing and hence $g(y)\le g(K)=0$

Comment: I got that $f'$ would be $\frac{1}{K} - \frac{1}{y}$ By differentiating as $$[ \ln(K/y) +Y/K - 1]' = -1/y + 1/k$$

Comment: @GabrielH, then you must have defined $f(y)$ to be $\ln(K/y)-(1-y/K)$. In that case you need to show that $f(y)\ge 0$, which I am sure you can show just following the method in my answer. Just remember that $\ln (K/y)=-\ln (y/K)=\ln y+\ln K$ and life will be much easier.

Comment: But $f'$ is negative on this interval, and $f(0) = 0$ so that would imply that $f$ is negative, no?

Comment: How can you evaluate $f(0)$? $y>0$ right? But don't you have $f(K)=0$? That will fix your problem.

Comment: So we have that $f(K) = 0$, and that the function is decreasing. Don't we need to show that $f$ remains positive?

Comment: The function is positive on $(0,K]$ since $f(0)=\infty$, $f(K)=0$, $f$ is decreasing on $(0,K]$ and $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Okay, this cleared it up for me, thanks so much for your patience!

Comment: You're welcome.